# Запрос на увеличение значения каждом новом поле на 1 от предыдущего

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня имеется таблица с полями:

```
   id           
+-------------+
   koll
+-------------+
   filter
```

Мне нужно в кажое новое поле "koll" записать значение "000001" увеличенное на 1 от предыдущего поля кроме "filter=45, 67 или 84". Тоесть должна получится следующая структура:

```
id   |  koll    |  filter
--------------------------
1    |  000001  |  20
2    |  000002  |  20
3    |  000003  |  20
4    |пропустить|  45
5    |пропустить|  67
6    |  000004  |  20
7    |  000005  |  20
8    |пропустить|  84
9    |  000006  |  20
10   |  000007  |  20
...  |  ...     |  ...
67   |  000053  |  20
...  |  ...     |  ...
344  |  000278  |  20
```

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет, в какую сторону смотреть или приведет пример sql запроса для заданной таблицы.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в условии задачи стоит требование увеличивать на единицу значение поля `koll` _предыдущей_ записи.

Comment: Не так, значит, понял...

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table if exists t1;    
create table t1 (id int,  koll int,  filter int);

insert into t1 values 
(1, 0, 20),
(2, 0, 20),
(3, 0, 20),
(4, 0, 45),
(5, 0, 67),
(6, 0, 20),
(7, 0, 20),
(8, 0, 84),
(9, 0, 20),
(10, 0, 20);

set @n=0;
update t1 set koll=@n:=@n+1 where filter not in (45,67,84);
select * from t1
```

Comment: И что делать при добавлении новой записи?

Comment: если всегда надо так, то, наверное,  делать триггер на добавление записи. я не мастак про это

Comment: `Да, данный запрос работает и увеличивает на 1, но поле "koll" получается со значениями "1,2,3, ..." а нужно чтобы были значения "000001, 000002, 000003, ..."`

Comment: как у вас описано это поле ?

Comment: `Если вы имеете в виду тип поля, тогда у поля "koll" тип "varchar"`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо "**splash58**"

Удалось добится поставленой задачи следующими запросами:

```
SET @n=1000000;
UPDATE t1 SET koll=@n:=@n+1 WHERE filter NOT IN (45,67,84);
UPDATE t1 SET koll = RIGHT(koll,LENGTH(koll)-1) WHERE filter NOT IN (45,67,84);
SELECT * FROM t1
```

Comment: RTFM [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad). [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e3b3/1)